# MVC App is no longer logging in through Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I have been developing an app using the Facebook add ons to enable Facebook users to log in and the app to access details such as profile pictures.

Yesterday the app was working perfectly and my development was continuing as normal.

This morning I tried to log in to check how far I'd got and was confronted with an Access Token error message.

Individual Partial Views would load up okay, but the site as a whole would not.  On further investigation I found that the log in screen was assigning a new Access Token, but by the time  the site tried to bring up the Master Page the token was null.

My log in is as follows :-

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Log On</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '***app no***',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true
      });

      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    };

    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email">
    Login with Facebook
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is frying my head.

The error that is returned is (OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Hope this is enough information for someone to find a solution.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a bit of an old one, but this may help someone else.  Found the answer in the end.  It was in the controller that I needed the following :-

```
var client = new FacebookClient(Session["FacebookToken"].ToString());    

dynamic me = client.Get("me");
```

This got an active Token which allowed me to access the info again.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the channel url i.e you website path(that can be localhost or server domain)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '***app no***',
    channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true
  });
```

Also you have to set your url path in developer.facebook.com from where you got your app-id.....

Comment: Tried this, but unfortunately it has made no difference to the outcome.  Still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found some information suggesting that changes to the Facebook SDK made at the start of December will be what caused my problems.  On the advice given I ran the reference updates on the Facebook references in my project.  This has removed the facebookSettings line from the Web.config and the following error message now appears six times in the warnings box.

> Reference to type 'Facebook.IFacebookApplication' claims it is defined
>   in '\packages\Facebook.6.1.4\lib\net40-client\Facebook.dll', but it
>   could not be
>   found \packages\FacebookWeb.5.4.1.0\lib\net40\Facebook.Web.dll

and the following error is produced on trying to run the program

> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Facebook.FacebookApplication' from assembly 'Facebook,
>   Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de'.
>
> ```
> Source Error: 
>
>
> Line 12:     public class HomeController : Controller
> Line 13:     {
> Line 14:         FacebookWebContext FBWebContext = new FacebookWebContext();
> Line 15:         FacebookWebClient FBWebClient = new FacebookWebClient();
> Line 16:
> ```